# VS Code SSH Remote Connection issues

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

I have been using VS Code and connecting remotely from home on my MacBookPro to work on a college project for the past month and for some reason it will not connect to the Computer Lab Server anymore.  No idea why this is happening but it just stopped working today.  I tried re-installing vs code and also installed it on my wife's computer but it still wont connect through remote ssh.  No idea why this is happening but now I have no way to debug my code and have to just edit everything using emacs through the terminal app on my mac.  I didn't make any changes from last night to this morning..  I can still ssh into the Computer Lab server from terminal fine.  Bellow is some of the log that seems to repeat itself while it is trying to connect using the extension: remote ssh.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, or are there other IDE's that are somewhat easy to connect remotely through ssh available for Mac?

MY LOG:

```
17:09:21.150] Log Level: 2
[17:09:21.152] remote-ssh@0.55.0
[17:09:21.152] darwin x64
[17:09:21.153] SSH Resolver called for "ssh- remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a226c696e75782e63732e75736d2e6d61696e652e656475222c2275736572223a22746b7766c6b227d", attempt 1
[17:09:21.154] SSH Resolver called for host: tkwilk@linux.cs.usm.maine.edu
[17:09:21.154] Setting up SSH remote "linux.cs.usm.maine.edu"
[17:09:21.158] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/9y/scfwvr0577qfgs_l_c5ym13m0000gq/T/vscode-remote-ssh-tkwilk@linux.cs.usm.maine.edu-install.lock
[17:09:21.192] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/twilk31888 1/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-tkwilk@linux.cs.usm.maine.edu-93c2f0fbf16c5a4b10e4d5f89737d9c2c25488a3-0.55.0/data.json
[17:09:21.194] Using commit id "93c2f0fbf16c5a4b10e4d5f89737d9c2c25488a3" and quality "stable" for server
[17:09:21.195] Install and start server if needed
[17:09:21.220] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[17:09:21.233] > OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

[17:09:21.249] askpass server listening on /var/folders/9y/scfwvr0577qfgs_l_c5ym13m0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-a45a56dcf061823c964fa6ae7ff720ac39d2477f.sock
[17:09:21.249] Spawning local server with {"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/9y/scfwvr0577qfgs_l_c5ym13m0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-c1cf58194111018972f9cf0cd413a94b7293bda9.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","54601","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","tkwilk@linux.cs.usm.maine.edu"],"dataFilePath":"/Users/twilk31888 1/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-tkwilk@linux.cs.usm.maine.edu-93c2f0fbf16c5a4b10e4d5f89737d9c2c25488a3-0.55.0/data.json"}
[17:09:21.249] Local server env: {"DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/twilk31888 1/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Renderer)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/twilk31888 1/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/9y/scfwvr0577qfgs_l_c5ym13m0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-a45a56dcf061823c964fa6ae7ff720ac39d2477f.sock"}
[17:09:21.262] Spawned 4239
[17:09:21.373] > local-server> Spawned ssh: 4240
[17:09:21.379] stderr> OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
[17:09:21.756] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:wny4SU/uVC6y9cUUH5kJnRe5SVWpBhWGABpWSYzMNG0
[17:09:22.132] stderr> Authenticated to linux.cs.usm.maine.edu ([130.111.131.121]:22).
[17:09:22.490] > ready: 946b80caa0f2
[17:09:22.553] > Linux 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020
[17:09:22.554] Platform: linux
[17:09:22.685] > 946b80caa0f2: running
[17:09:22.713] > Acquiring lock on /home/students/tkwilk/.vscode-server/bin/93c2f0fbf16c5a4b10e4d5f89737d9c2c25488a3/vscode-remote-lock.tkwilk.93c2f0fbf16c5a4b10e4d5f89737d9c2c25488a3
> Installation already in progress...
> 946b80caa0f2##24##
[17:09:22.714] Received install output: 946b80caa0f2##24##
[17:09:22.714] Server installation process already in progress - waiting and retrying
[17:09:22.714] Terminating local server
[17:09:22.740] Local server exit: 15
```

Answer (score 29):

The key info is provided at the line

> ```
> [17:09:22.713] > Acquiring lock on /home/students/tkwilk/.vscode-server/bin/93c2f0fbf16c5a4b10e4d5f89737d9c2c25488a3/vscode-remote-lock.tkwilk.93c2f0fbf16c5a4b10e4d5f89737d9c2c25488a3
> ```

If you could `ssh` into the server and remove the file by

```
rm -rf /home/students/tkwilk/.vscode-server/bin/93c2f0fbf16c5a4b10e4d5f89737d9c2c25488a3/vscode-remote-lock.tkwilk.93c2f0fbf16c5a4b10e4d5f89737d9c2c25488a3
```

then reboot the vscode and try to connect, things should be fine.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well. :)

Comment: Should be tagged as the answer

Answer (score 11):

Encountered the same problem on two servers with two different causes:

1. One problem is solved by referring to this issue: [#2805](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2805)

   - Command Palette -> Select "Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host..."
   - Remove the directory of "~/.vscode-server" on remote server.
2. The other problems, is caused by running out of storage quota on that server. And the issue was automatically solved when the quota was increased.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the [`microsoft/vscode-remote-release`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues) I see, like [issue 2901](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2901), are about a failed symlink on the target server.

If  you can ssh in command line, try and rename `/home/students/tkwilk/.vscode-server` in order to force a complete re-installation of the SSH remote plugin by VSCode.

```
mv ~/.vscode-server ~/.vscode-server-old
```

Try and connect to that server through VSCode and see if the issue persists, when it tries to redo the complete vscode-server SSH setup.

Answer (score 2):

I found a new reason, but it may be rare:

> Before I found this problem, I had updated and modified the linux kernel of the remote virtual machine, and modified the `UTS_SYSNAME` located in `/include/linux/uts.h`;
>
> ```
> #define UTS_SYSNAME "Linux Clstilmldy-LZM"
> // #define UTS_SYSNAME "Linux"
> ```

So I met this problem, but I never found a feasible solution;

I carefully looked at the vscode output and found that vscode remote ssh: `Unsupported platform: Linux Clstilmldy LZM`;

```
[16:38:25.333] SSH Resolver called for host: Ubuntu
[16:38:25.334] Setting up SSH remote "Ubuntu"
...
[16:38:35.555] Got password response
[16:38:35.555] "install" wrote data to terminal: "******"
[16:38:35.574] > 
[16:38:36.069] > ac25402ecd5f: running
[16:38:36.086] > Unsupported platform: Linux Clstilmldy-LZM
[16:38:36.096] > ac25402ecd5f: start
```

I guess that vscode remote ssh does not recognize system names other than Linux, Mac, and Windows, so I changed this line back.

I recompile and install the kernel.

okkk, I solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered this problem. The issue was related to locking, and the fact that my host had a home directory that uses NFS. This is common for universities student accounts and other employers.
Removing the lockfile as suggested only temporarily and partially solves the issue.
VSCode Remote-SSH has a [setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j58qZ.png) to create the lockfile in /temp instead of the home directory. Enabling that setting fixed the problem for me.
View > Extensions > Remote - SSH > Gear Icon > Extension Settings > Check Remote.SSH: Lockfiles In Tmp

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, since none of these worked for me. Try toggling off the following setting in VSCode: `remote.SSH.useFlock`