# VC Code can't SSH into Google Cloud (stderr> OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3)

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, ssh, vscode-remote

So I've been using google cloud GPUs for the past week. I've been having a different problem every time I connect via VS Code. But anyway, this time VS Code is not asking me for the password to connect via SSH. It just hangs at `stderr> OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3` and then I get a timeout.

I tried [changing Remote-SSH extension version](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2545), but that didn't work. Didn't expect it to since it hasn't been updated in the last 3 weeks.

I tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298741/vs-code-ssh-remote-connection-issues), but none of them worked.

I can SSH via terminal and the browser, but VS Code is giving me an issue.

Any ideas on what I should try? Here's the output:

```
[10:29:22.090] Spawned 72151
[10:29:22.244] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=72168
[10:29:22.247] stderr> OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3 ***** THIS IS WHERE IT HANGS *****
[10:30:37.637] stderr> ssh: connect to host [address] port 22: Operation timed out
[10:30:37.638] > local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down
[10:30:37.649] Local server exit: 0
[10:30:37.649] Received install output: local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=72168
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
ssh: connect to host [address] port 22: Operation timed out
local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down

[10:30:37.653] Resolver error: Error: The operation timed out
    at Function.Offline (/Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:585270)
    at /Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:582907
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:583059)
    at Object.e [as tryInstallWithLocalServer] (/Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:624370)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:643503
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:647221)
    at async /Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:622842
    at async T (/Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:619348)
    at async Object.t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:622457)
    at async Object.t.resolve (/Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:644831)
    at async /Users/[username]/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.82.1/out/extension.js:1:727005
[10:30:37.662] ------
```

EDIT: It seems to be related to "host key" since I'm getting the following output:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:[key].
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/[username]/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /Users/[username]/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts:6
ECDSA host key for compute.[nums] has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I'm assuming I need to update the key in `/Users/[username]/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts`, but I'm not sure where to find the correct key.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the fingerprint for the VM that you are trying to ssh. This fingerprint has changed, and this information is stored in your desktop in the file `known_hosts` located at `~/.ssh`. So, once you delete the file, you will be able to reconnect to your VM with the new fingerprint.

The fingerprint of your VM could be changed by a normal behavior like an OS upgrade executed by you, or maybe an update from its IP address if it was configured to use a dynamic IP address instead of a fixed IP address.

Because of this, it's important to be sure that the change was made by a normal behavior and not by any suspicious activity.

In this link, you can find more information about how to securely connect to your VM [instances](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue.

I'm not actually sure which part solved it for sure, but I deleted the file called `google_compute_known_hosts` in `/Users/[username]/.ssh` on my Mac. Then I reran (I did this when I first got the SSH to work with VS Code) the following command in the command-line: `gcloud compute config-ssh`. I retried connecting to the VM with VS Code via Remote-SSH and I was finally asked for the passphrase to connect. I'm not sure what changed, but either I was previously using VPN or something changed when I went to work at a café yesterday. I think it's something to do on GCP's end which involved changing the host key.

Anyways, hopefully, I can just follow those steps again if it ever happens again.